# How to disable "no-results-text"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to disable the no-results-text in jQuerys Chosen 1.1.0.

I have tried some codechanges, but not with the expected results. All I reached is that I disabled the whole search-function or that the no-results-text was "undefined".

Where is the key to disable only this no-results-text like "No results match" and nothing else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's no-results-text?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what is wrong. Show us your code and maybe a screenshot of what is wrong.

Comment: Also it would help if add what you've tried so far, chosen plugin 1.1.0 can be found here: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases, 
Latest version has the option `$(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});` is this no valid in 1.1.0? can't you update to the latest version if isn't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the release 1.1.0 documentation, is an option you can set when you first call the `chosen` function
Example:

```
$(".my_select_box").chosen(
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
    width: "95%"
  );
```

or

```
 $(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});
```

**Sample** using `&nbsp` entity to disable any text more than the one typed

```html
<!Doctype html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>    
  </body>  
  <script>
     $(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "&nbsp"});
  </script>
</html>
```

You could also add this css within your head tag after you load jquery chosen plugin and its' css:

```
<style>
      li.no-results {
       visibility:hidden;
      }
</style>
```

Or modify the source of the chosen.css and add `visibility:hidden` to the `no-results` class that would remove any message/text if there'are no results in the search

**Sample** adding `visibility:hidden` to the `no-results` class to hide any text

```html
<!Doctype html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    <style>
        li.no-results{visibility:hidden;}
    </style>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
       
    </select>    
  </body>  
  <script>
     $(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "This message is hidden"});
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! Changes in the css are working fine! Simple solution, but needed your input to get it ;-) I rated your answer as useful, but my reputation is too low, so that it is not public to see...